# Scraping Closing Price from yFinance with Python(BS/Requests)

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the closing price from the historical data with Bs. However the closing price has the same tag as all other columns(open,high,low,etc).

`soup.find_all('td', class_="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)")` returns all data under all those columns. But I'm just trying to find only the data under the closing price.

`soup.find_all('td', class_="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)") [3]` returns the first closing price in the whole table. However I'm trying to get all the closing price for different dates.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please post the relevant URL as well.

Comment: https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HSBA.L/history?period1=1645548051&period2=1677084051&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true

Sorry..This is the url.

Answer (score 1):

Use following css selector to get the value of closing price.

```
for closingprice in soup.select("table[data-test='historical-prices'] >tbody td:nth-of-type(5)"):
    print(closingprice.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked perfectly and I learnt something new in CSS.